# Replacing results with pre-defined values if LEFT JOIN returns empty result

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have left join expression like this:

```
SELECT
    p.val_p1, 
    p.val_p2, 
    p.val_p3, 
    a.val_a1, 
    a.val_a2, 
    a.val_a3
FROM TABLE_P p
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a
    ON p.val_p3 = a.val_a3
    WHERE <conditions>
```

Search works well and i get output like this:

| val_p1 | val_p2 | val_p3 | val_a1 | val_a2 | val_a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

But if LEFT JOIN returns empty result I have no output at all. What I need in such case is to replace search results with some other values. For example like this:

| val_p1 | val_p2 | val_p3 | val_a1 | val_a2 | val_a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val_p1 not found | val_p2 not found | not found | not found | not found | not found |

I tried to use CASE expressions

```
SELECT
    CASE p.val_p1
           WHEN NULL THEN 'not found'
           ELSE p.val_p1
        END AS "title_p1", 
    CASE p.val_p2
           WHEN NULL THEN 'not found'
           ELSE p.val_p2
        END AS "title_p2",
    CASE p.val_p3
           WHEN NULL THEN 'not found'
           ELSE p.val_p3
        END AS "title_p3",
        etc
```

but LEFT JOIN returns no result anyway. Where is the way to replace empty results with my default values?

Comment: Have you tried `COALESCE`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I have no output at all*"? It does output `NULL`, and only in the `val_a1`/`val_a3`/`val_a3` columns, no?

Comment: I don't think `CASE p.val_p1 WHEN NULL THEN …` works - nothing is equal to `NULL`. You'd need to use `CASE WHEN p.val_p1 IS NULL THEN …`, but like @Vérace said, you really should just use `COALESCE(p.val_p1, …)`.

Comment: to Verace Yes I tried to use COALESCE like this: 
SELECT
    COALESCE(p.val_p1,'value1'), 
    COALESCE(p.val_p2,'value2') etc
but if join returns null I have anyway empty output

Comment: To Bergi
Yes, of course, You right. Output is the columns with null values

Comment: To Bergi:
 CASE WHEN p.val_p1 IS NULL THEN 'value1' ELSE p.val_p1 END AS "val_p1" works with the same result - NULL output

Comment: @Seller_V - if you want to ping me, you have to use `@` then my handle `Vérace` (no spaces) - otherwise I won't know that you've replied. p.s. welcome to SE!

Comment: @Seller_V That should work. Please provide a [mcve] with the exact actual query and the table definitions and some sample value. You can [edit] your question to include them as SQL code, ideally so that we could copy-paste it into e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_16 and it would run there

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/f_S3O65X) - it seems to work fine!

Comment: There is something wrong with your WHERE clause (which you haven't shown us so we can't know what is wrong with it).  Please show us a real example.

Comment: @Vérace thank you very much for this useful tool!
I have modified your query to get an example closer to my situation. Please look there [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/ykzgXxqx)

Comment: @Seller_V Thanks. Now what is the exact query giving you troubles (unexpected results)?

Comment: @Vérace if I use name 'Otto' like You can see in query it works fine and I get five filled columns with joined information. Ok. When I try name 'Henry' which is not present in table p (employee war fired for example) I get columns with NULLs, and this is correct. What I need - columns filled with 'not found' (or any other text) instead of NULLs.

Comment: "*When I try name 'Henry' which is not present in table p I get columns with NULLs, and this is correct.*" - no you don't. You don't get any rows at all for names not present in the table. The `LEFT JOIN` means that you get rows that contain cells with `NULL` only for employees *that exist* but for which no department could be found.

Comment: @Bergi of course You right. Sorry I'm not good yet in sql. But the goal still the same - cells filled with my text instead of "no rows at all"

Comment: You shouldn't need that unless you are looking for multiple names? Regardless, you'll first need to select the name in relation that you then can left-join against, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/tiUWzevk

Comment: @Bergi  No, there is no need to use search for multiple names. Always one name used.

Comment: Then you should probably handle the case where there is no result on the client anyway.

Comment: @Seller_V - take a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ys8fMUOj) - if there's no Henry, you can't expect any results anywhere - but if the name exists but no corresponding address, then you get your desired result!

Comment: @Vérace thank you, the trick is good but this is not copletely what I need.  Search is performed by Name only and "if there's no Henry, you can't expect any results anywhere" then the goal is to substitute the absent data with my text.

Comment: Good news! Issue is solved. If you are interested look here https://dbfiddle.uk/HwBoRvkE . Thank you for help!